# Find a Value in a column and sum up the next values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search the column which says "total" and need to start adding the values just next to the "total" column

The text"total" is in column "o" and the values are in the columns p,q,r,s..

i need to sum up the values as 1265+1789+2099.25 ... and show the output sum in any of the cell.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

So this would be something like:

```
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim tot As Double
Dim fnd As Boolean
Dim cellTx As String

tot = 0
fnd = False

For r = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        cellTx = ActiveSheet.UsedRange(r, c).Value
        If fnd Then
            If IsNumeric(cellTx) Then tot = tot + Val(cellTx)
        Else
            If cellTx = "total" Then fnd = True
        End If
    Next
    If fnd Then Exit For
Next
```

The total would then be stored in the `tot` variable. This code may require some debugging and error handling

Comment: Hi There, i want to find the column which has a value "total" in it and then start adding the number's from the next row available. for example if the "total" is in cell Q1 i want to add the values from next cell R1 to the last cell in that Row.

Comment: @user2831590: You mean that if Q1 has total, you want to add R1 to R99 for instance? Do you then want to add column S onwards as well?